# Defining ON DELETE CASCADE in pgAdmin 3

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I can't find how to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` rule in pgAdmin 3. I want to achieve that if a record in the parent table is deleted, then the corresponding records in the child table will automatically be deleted.

Still, I can't find this option when creating tables visually in pgAdmin.

I can see something like this:

[image: pgAdmin menu]

But none of this seems to offers option to achieve what I want... Any ideas how to do it through pgAdmin?

Comment: Why not just do it in SQL? It's **much** better to put your DDL statements in scripts anyway (so you can put them under version control, can deploy them easily to other environments and many more reasons, can re-create your database from scratch, ...)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well I can do it by the hand...But I was wondering how to do it through pgAdmin as well...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, I just found it, it was simple, but still I will post it for future readers with a same question. When creating foreign key constraint there is Action tab and from there it is possible to define what you want to happen on update, or on delete:

[image]